# How to filter Non ASCII character in a column from a Teradata Table

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I wanted to count No of Special Characters(Non ASCII) inserted into a Column.
Below is the code that i wrote ,which is not working as expected,

```
  SELECT count(BEST_ADDR_1) Inv_cnt
FROM DP_VEDW_SRC_MDB_NGN.ACCT_SUM_VIEW 
WHERE BEST_ADDR_1 NOT LIKE '%[^a-z0-9A-Z]%')
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Teradata does't support character ranges in LIKE. but you can use `RegExp_Replace`.

Remove the non-ASCII characters and check the remaining character length

```
SUM(Char_Length(RegExp_Replace(BEST_ADDR_1, '[a-z0-9]', '', 1, 0, 'i')))
```

Comment: I think the OP asks about those char byte values that starts from 128..not just alphabets and numbers..

Comment: As I read the answer, `REGEXP_REPLACE` will search `BEST_ADDR_1` for `[a-z0-9`] and replace it with `’’` starting with the first character (1) and replace all occurrences (0) using a case insensitive match.  The resulting string will then be passed to `CHAR_LENGTH` to calculate the length of the remaining string. `SUM()` will aggregate the result for every row.